# How to parse Wufoo form webhook hash to get forms labels and values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, wufoo

I would like to parse a hash which I receive from Wufoo Webhook API. I am doing this for multiple forms so I can't hardcode values like: `params['Field5']` because I don't know how many fields I have.

```
  >> params.class
  => Hash
  >> params
  => {"FieldStructure"=>
       "{\"Fields\":[
         {\"Title\":\"Company Name\",\"Type\":\"text\",\"ID\":\"Field6\"},
         {\"Title\":\"Email\",\"Type\":\"email\",\"ID\":\"Field5\"}
        ]}",
 "Field6"=>"testse",
 "Field5"=>"gdsgfdgdf@fd.pl",
 "CreatedBy"=>"public",
 "DateCreated"=>"2013-04-10 07:38:09",
 "EntryId"=>"21"}
```

Basically, I would like to create an object from hash above with attributes:

```
company_name: "testse", email: "gdsgfdgdf@fd.pl"
```

Comment: your input Hash is very ugly. Can you re-edit it?

Comment: Sure. Full version here: https://gist.github.com/a1920bf86346e8d24fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Scan the FieldStructure string to determine the id for the desired fields.
2. Then use the ids to find the desired values in the params hash

Example:

```
params  =  {"FieldStructure"=>
  "{\"Fields\":[{\"Title\":\"Company Name\",\"Instructions\":\"\",\"IsRequired\":\"0\",\"ClassNames\":\"\",\"DefaultVal\":\"\",\"Page\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"text\",\"ID\":\"Field6\"},
  {\"Title\":\"Email\",\"Instructions\":\"\",\"IsRequired\":\"0\",\"ClassNames\":\"\",\"DefaultVal\":\"\",\"Page\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"email\",\"ID\":\"Field5\"}]}",
 "FormStructure"=>
  "{\"Name\":\"TestForm\",\"Description\":\"This is my form. Please fill it out. It's awesome!\",\"RedirectMessage\":\"Great! Thanks for filling out my form!\",\"Url\":\"testform\",\"Email\":null,\"IsPublic\":\"1\",\"Language\":\"english\",\"StartDate\":\"2000-01-01 12:00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"2030-01-01 12:00:00\",\"EntryLimit\":\"0\",\"DateCreated\":\"2013-04-09 06:44:12\",\"DateUpdated\":\"2013-04-10 05:25:55\",\"Hash\":\"z7x3p3\"}",
 "Field6"=>"testse",
 "Field5"=>"gdsgfdgdf@fd.pl",
 "CreatedBy"=>"public",
 "DateCreated"=>"2013-04-10 07:38:09",
 "EntryId"=>"21",
 "IP"=>"46.205.117.55",
 "HandshakeKey"=>""}

 fields = params['FieldStructure'].scan(/Title\":\"(.+?)\".+?ID\":\"(.+?)\"/)
 #=> [["Company Name", "Field6"], ["Email", "Field5"]]

 Hash[fields.collect{ |field| 
   [
     field[0].gsub(/\s+/, "_").downcase.to_sym, 
     params[field[1]]
   ]
 }]
 #=> {:company_name=>"testse", :email=>"gdsgfdgdf@fd.pl"}
```

Comment: Justin do you understand why scanning fields are not working when I have this params in single line? => https://gist.github.com/regedarek/a1920bf86346e8d24fee

Comment: The check for text between the title value and the id value was greedy, so what you got was the company name title matched with the email id. It should be `.scan(/Title\":\"(.+?)\".+?ID\":\"(.+?)\"/)`, which has an extra `?` in the middle.